# The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0 is not registered. If the 32-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 64-bit mode

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, ssis, office365, etl

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 (Pro) Version 16.9.4
Microsoft Access for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.014326.20782) 64-bit

> Package Validation Error (Package Validation Error)
>
> ===================================
>
> Error at Refresh ACCESS tables [FEE TABLE [73]]: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
> AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager
> "Datebase.accdb" failed with error code 0xC0209302.  There may be
> error messages posted before this with more information on why the
> AcquireConnection method call failed.
>
> Error at Refresh ACCESS tables [SSIS.Pipeline]: FEE TABLE failed
> validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
>
> Error at Refresh ACCESS tables [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component
> failed validation.
>
> Error at Refresh ACCESS tables: There were errors during task
> validation.
>
> Error at APP_Universe [Connection manager "Database2.accdb"]: The
> requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0 is not registered.
> If the 32-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 64-bit mode.
> Error code: 0x00000000. An OLE DB record is available.  Source:
> "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154
> Description: "Class not registered".
>
> (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

Answer (score 0):

You should download the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920).

First, run the 32-bit installation. Once finished, open the command prompt, change the current directory to the 64-bit installation directory, and run the following command:

```
AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe /quiet
```

This will install both versions on your computer.